# Docker build windows container run command

Tags: docker, windows-container

All of a sudden Docker Build is not working on windows container.

I have Windows 11 VM and have below docker versions

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

Simple Docker file with hello world fails at the RUN command

Docker build fails with below error

```
" encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (0x3fa)"
```

Tried by downgrading to a different version but still same error.  Below are my VM details

```
Docker Info 

Server:
 Containers: 18
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 18
 Images: 65
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 22000 (22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 2009 (OS Build 22000.1936)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
```

Followed below thread to downgrade to desktop version 2.2.0.3 but still a similar error.

Does anyone has any solution to resolve this ?
Any alternative to do docker build ?

Here is my simple dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903
COPY hello.txt C:
RUN ECHO "HELLO-WORLD"
CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
```

it fails at RUN Command, the issue is with RUN command

Comment: Can you please provide your dockerfile so we can understand what it's trying to build?

Comment: updated the question with my Dockerfile contents

Comment: Let me try that with your dockerfile - will report back

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to repro your scenario, but here are a few things:

- First, the 1903 image is not supported anymore. My recommendation is to with the ltsc2022 image.
- Your RUN ECHO "HELLO-WORLD" line doesn't do anything to the image. It's running at build time, so it's additional line that doesn't add anything to the final image. My recommendation is to either write the "Hello World" to the file before it's copied, or use PowerShell to manipulate the file, which would make the image unnecessarily larger.

Here's a Dockerfile you can leverage:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
COPY hello.txt C:
CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
```

With this dockerfile and the hello.txt file on the same folder (notice my hello.txt file has "Hello World!" in it) I ran the following:

```
PS C:\tools\Docker test> docker build -t testimage:v1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
 ---> 8d8c1e713e14
Step 2/3 : COPY hello.txt C:
 ---> 02dae6250c53
Step 3/3 : CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
 ---> Running in 31c7532a5914
Removing intermediate container 31c7532a5914
 ---> 81de44276c9c
Successfully built 81de44276c9c
Successfully tagged testimage:v1
PS C:\tools\Docker test> docker run testimage:v1
Hello World!
PS C:\tools\Docker test>
```

I'm also using Windows 11 and have updated Docker Desktop recently. Can you try these steps?