# run command fails in Windows Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I switched to Windows container from Docker Desktop in OS Windows 11

One thing I observed is that during the docker build if my dockerfile contains any RUN command it fails with the below error

This docker desktop is installed in almost 10 VM's and across all the VM's its the same error

```
"encountered an error during hcsshim::System::Start: failure in a Windows system call: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion. (0x3fa)

Docker Info 

Server:
 Containers: 18
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 18
 Images: 65
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 22000 (22000.1.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 2009 (OS Build 22000.1936)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
```

Here is my simple dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
COPY hello.txt C:
RUN ECHO "HELLO-WORLD"
CMD ["cmd", "/C", "type C:\\hello.txt"]
```

What I tried

1. Tried uninstall and install of different docker desktop versions
2. Removed recent security updates on Windows11
3. Sometimes the image build succeeds, again after few tries fails with above error
4. Tried with different windows base images, no luck
5. Tried docker system prune, no luck

Are there any alternative to docker to build windows containers ?

Comment: This question is prettu much the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76414124/docker-build-windows-container-run-command?noredirect=1#comment134752591_76414124 I have provided some information there. Can you please check and see if this works?

Comment: Answering my own question, fix is from the GroupPolicy editor  to change the key "Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff setting” to “ENABLED